# Time sensitive data in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm building an application in `Node.js` and `MongoDB`, and the application has something of `time-valid data`, meaning if some piece of data was inserted into the database.

I'd like to remove it from the database (via code) after three days (or any amount of days/time spread).

Currently, my solution is to have some sort of member in my `Schema` that checks when it was actually posted and subsequently removes it when the current time is past 3 days from the insertion, but I'm having trouble in figuring out a good way to write it in code.

Are there any standard ways to accomplish something like this?

Comment: MongoDB has a [TTL index, allowing you to let documents expire](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). Better native solutions than programing an extra job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways to accomplish this with a TTL index. A TTL index will let you define a special type of index on a BSON Date field that will automatically delete documents based on age. First, you will need to have a BSON Date field in your documents. If you don't have one, this won't work. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date

Then you can either delete all documents after they reach a certain age, or set expiration dates for each document as you insert them.

For the first case, assuming you wanted to delete documents after 1 hour you would create this index:

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

assuming you had a createdAt field that was a date type. MongoDB will take care of deleting all documents in the collection once they reach 3600 seconds (or 1 hour) old.

For the second case, you will create an index with expireAfterSeconds set to 0 on a different field:

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

If you then insert a document with an expireAt field set to a date mongoDB will delete that document at that date and time:

```
db.mycollection.insert( {
   "expireAt": new Date('June 6, 2014 13:52:00'),
   "mydata": "data"
} )
```

You can read more detail about how to use TTL indexes here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/